# Easy Question: Filter a View By Tax Term Menu Style Not Exposed Filters

Tags: views

I dont know if im having a blonde moment or not. Im sure i learnt how to do this about 9 years ago way back on drupal 4 but ....well i seem stuck.

I have a page view. /match-previews. Its using the same vocab as im using across my website. I was wanting to create a menu link in the sidebar to each football league. I have it set up with an exposed filter but really i would prefer to have it as a menu system.

Ive tried cloning the page and adding a /match-previews/% page but thats where i seem to be stuck. Maybe just making up some normal pages and making a block view for each and taking the term from the page could be the way to go.

Can anyone put me out my misery as ive been at it too long for now tonight.

Thanks

my page is here if it helps
http://ukfootballbet.com/match-previews/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the /match-previews/% as a contextual filter (advanced tab).  Here is a good tutorial on setting it up (http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/using-drupal-contextual-filters-views)

Comment: thanks Geoff looks good (and familiar) ill try it in a bit and come back and click your answer. sod it lets click the now as that is the way to do it.